# How to remove all characters before a specific character in Cognos Report Studio 10.2

Tags: string, character, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I have columns with different company names. In front of each company name there is a Company_ID. After the Company_ID a specific character = _ divides the ID from the Name. For example i have

111_Mercedes
11B4324_Apple 
38A_Google 
A1ZH8_Airline

I would like to remove all characters including the specific character.

Result should be
Mercedes
Apple
Google
Airline

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the value always contain 4 company names?

Comment: No, this is only an example. There are at least over 1000 Company names.

Comment: SQL is not good at looping through thousands of operations on a single value.  It can be done, but in a stored procedure, not a simple query.  You should ask your DBA to create an ETL to parse this data and put the individual values in another table.

Comment: Maybe a stored proc or SQL function to return the desired result (instead of another table)

Answer (score 0):

**If this is all in one data item and you need a pattern removed, try this:**
As an example, 111_Mercedes 11B4324_Apple 38A_Google

The name starts with _  and ends with a space
Because of this, we can use the replace function to set up the process in two steps

**1) Wrap the undesired portion in brackets**
Sql would look like this

```
select                                                        
concat('<',replace(
    replace('111_Mercedes 11B4324_Apple 38A_Google',' ','<')
        ,'_','>'))
 FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
```

**The result would look like**
<111>Mercedes<11B4324>Apple<38A>Google

**2) Then remove the content in the brackets**
Sql would look like this:

```
Select trim(REGEXP_REPLACE(
'<111>Mercedes<11B4324>Apple<38A>Google'
, '<(.*?)>',' ',1,0,'c'))                                            
FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
```

**The result would look like this**
Mercedes Apple Google

For Cognos try to use the functions in the data item definitions

```
BracketCompany =  concat('<',replace(replace([Company ID],' ','<'),'_','>'))
```

Then another data item over this, to remove the content within the brackets

```
FinalCompany = trim(REGEXP_REPLACE([BracketCompany], '<(.*?)>',' ',1,0,'c'))
```

Comment: That would return `Mercedes 11B4324_Apple 38A_Google A1ZH8_Airline`.  I think Kre is looking for `Mercedes Apple Google Airline`.